# First fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ of $\mathbb{R^3} \setminus \{$a circumference $\cup$ a line tangent to a point on the circumference$\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have to find the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ of $X=\mathbb{R^3} \setminus \{$a line $\cup$ a circumference$\}$.

- Line passing through the centre of the circle, we have: $\pi_1(X) \cong\left(\mathbb{R^3}\setminus\{0\}\right)\times S^1 \cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$
- Line "out" from the circumference, using the Van Kampen theorem, $X=A\cup B$ where $A=\mathbb{R^3} \setminus S^1$, $B= \mathbb{R^3} \setminus \{$the line$\}$ and $A\cap B=\mathbb{R^3}$, we have $\pi_1(X) \cong \cfrac{\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}}{\{e\}} \cong\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$

What about the $\pi_1(X)$ when the line tangent to a point on the circle? I have no ideas

Comment: Your last $X$ is homotopy equivalent to "$8$" (bouquet of two circles), so you get a free group with two generators.

Comment: Very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3026468.

Comment: @user8268 how to see that? Because at first glance I would have said $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$: thinking at the loop which "passes" around the intersection gives me the idea that the generators can commute.

Comment: I'll try to explain: $\Bbb R^3$ minus a circle deformation retracts onto a sphere with a diameter. In place of a circle and a tangent line, let me rather remove the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=0$, and the two half-lines $x\leq-1$, $x\geq 1$ ($y=z=0$). This thing now retracts to a sphere with a diameter, but with two holes in the sphere (that's where the half-lines cross it), which in turn retracts to a "$\ominus$" shape, and that is homotopy equivalent to "$8$"